# Celery or beanstalkd or both?

Tags: python, celery, task-queue, beanstalkd

I know (but I do not understand) that Celery can use Beanstalk as delivery mechanism.

From the [Beanstalkd Homepage](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/)

"Beanstalk is a simple, fast work queue."

From the [Celery Homepage](http://celeryproject.org/)

"It’s a task queue with focus on real-time processing, while also supporting task scheduling."

That seems pretty similar to me. So, why would I choose Celery instead of plain beanstalk? Or why would I choose beanstalk instead of full-grown Celery?

I would like to add a task/work queue to my webapp, but I am not sure which way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant discussion in the [Celery mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/celery-users/CUkJkb34GUM/discussion)